# How to generate a list from a pandas DataFrame with the column name and column values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe object that looks like this:

```
   one  two  three  four  five
0    1    2      3     4     5
1    1    1      1     1     1
```

I'd like to generate a list of lists objects where the first item is the column label and the remaining list values are the column data values:

```
nested_list = [['one', 1, 1]
               ['two', 2, 1]
               ['three', 3, 1]
               ['four', 4, 1]
               ['five', 5, 1]]
```

How can I do this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simplest way is probably `list(dt.T.itertuples())` (where `dt` is your dataframe).  This generates a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about itertuples().

Comment: I also didn't realise itertuples was there... - elegant +1

Comment: Creates list of tuples though not list of lists

Answer (score 10):

@BrenBarn answer above yields a list of tuples not a list of list as asked in question.  I specifically needed a list of lists to be able to write the dataframe into spreadsheed using DataNitro.   Adapted the above example with list comprehension:

```
[list(x) for x in dt.T.itertuples()]
```

This yields the result as needed

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking if you want nested lists (and not a list of tuples) you can do

```
df.values.tolist()
```

as df.values is a numpy array. That will give you a list of lists as requested:

```
[[0.0001313652121930252, 3.5915356549999985e-05], 
 [3.5915356549999985e-05, 0.00011634321240684215]]
```

Answer (score 3):

My naive approach would be using iteritems with 'll' as a list of lists and l as a single list.

```
df = DataFrame({'one':[1,1], 'two':[2,1], 'three':[3,1], 'four':[3,1] })

ll = []

for idx,row in df.iteritems():
    l = row.values.tolist()
    l.insert(0,idx)
    ll.append(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but this makes more sense to me than these other answers.

If this is your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1, 1], 'three': [3, 1], 'four': [4, 1],
           'five': [5, 1], 'two': [2, 1]},
          columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'])
```

Do this:

```
df.T.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Result

```
[['one', 1, 1], ['two', 2, 1], ['three', 3, 1], ['four', 4, 1], ['five', 5, 1]]
```