# Pandas keyerror while dropping value from a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in Python and getting an error while trying to drop values from a column in pandas dataframe. I keep getting Keyerror after sometime. Here is the code snippet:

```
for i in data['FilePath'].keys():
if '.' not in data['FilePath'][i]:
    value = data['FilePath'][i]
    data = data[data['FilePath'] != value]
```

I keep getting Keyerror near the line "if '.' not in data['FilePath'][i]". Please help me fix this error

Comment: can you add a sample from your data?

Comment: FilePath                                     BytesAccessed DateTime       
0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5       832.0    [28/Jun/2018:11:53:09]

Comment: @nimrodz I have added the sample data. The columns are FilePAth, BytesAccessed and DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your logic correctly, then you should be be able to do this without a loop. From what I can see, it looks like you want to drop rows if the `FilePath` column does not begin with `.`. If this is correct, then below is one way to do this:

Create sample data using [nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32857631/4057186)

```
d = [
    ['BytesAccessed','FilePath','DateTime'],
    [0, '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 832.0', '[28/Jun/2018:11:53:09]'], 
    [1, './lib/x86-linux-gnu/yourtext.so.6 932.0', '[28/Jun/2018:11:53:09]'],
    [2, '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mytes0', '[28/Jun/2018:11:53:09]'],
    ]
data = pd.DataFrame(d[1:], columns=d[0])
print(data)

   BytesAccessed                                   FilePath                DateTime
0              0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 832.0  [28/Jun/2018:11:53:09]
1              1    ./lib/x86-linux-gnu/yourtext.so.6 932.0  [28/Jun/2018:11:53:09]
2              2               /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mytes0  [28/Jun/2018:11:53:09]
```

Filtered data to drop rows that do not contain `.` [at any location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47769099/4057186) in the `FilePath` column

```
data_filtered = (data.set_index('FilePath')
                    .filter(like='.', axis=0)
                    .reset_index())[data.columns]
print(data_filtered)

   BytesAccessed                                   FilePath                DateTime
0              0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 832.0  [28/Jun/2018:11:53:09]
1              1    ./lib/x86-linux-gnu/yourtext.so.6 932.0  [28/Jun/2018:11:53:09]
```

Comment: Thanks @W R for this option. I am looking if FilePath contains '.' because there are many entries which doesn't contain any '.'

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional info. I've modified the sample data to intentionally contain one row (3rd row) that does not contain any `.`. I also changed the pandas filter to return any rows that contain a `.`.

Comment: Thank you so much @W R! This works great. I had no idea that I could use an option like 'filter'.