# Convert Triple Nested List to Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists

I have this list of data that I want to convert to dataframe:

[image]

There is 22 indices (let's rename it as docs), and if we examine each doc (let's see doc 0):

[image]

Now, I want to translate this triple-nested list into dataframe, where its columns are `'Word'`, `'Pos'`, and `'Biotag'`. If we take an example from second picture, the table would be :

```
Word        Pos      Biotag
____________________________
S7892537B1  NNP      O
-           :        O
High        JJ       O
...
```

However, this is only data from first doc. I want to add all 22 documents into single dataframe, and I want to add 'Docs' column which indicates the document of each entry, such as it would be:

```
Word        Pos      Biotag    Docs
___________________________________
S7892537B1  NNP      O         0
-           :        O         0
High        JJ       O         0
...
encoding    VBG      O         2
Dev.        NNP      I         2
...
et          NNP      I         22
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857544/nested-list-to-pandas-dataframe-with-headers) and [that](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-using-list-of-tuples/), however the returning columns always didn't match. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For a single doc:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df['Value'].values.tolist(), columns=['Word', 'Pos', 'Biotag'])
```

How do you want to process multiple docs?

Comment: what is the variable for list from this line?

Comment: @rayyar df['Value'].values will get the values, and tolist() returns a list for pd.DataFrame to use. Hope it helps.